# Meaning of Convergence of Simple Random Variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I would like to derive the expectation of a discrete non-negative random variable, $X: \Omega \rightarrow B(\mathbb{R})$, using the expectations of a sequence of a sequence of simple random variables, $X_n$ that converge to $X$. I do so via the theorem:

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable. Then its expectation is defined as:

$$
E(X) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(X_n)
$$

for an arbitrary increasing sequence of non-negative simple random variables $X_n$ converging to $X$.

My understanding of the convergence of a random variable is pointwise convergence of functions. I.e $X_n \rightarrow X$ if $X_n(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Now is the following true: $X_n$ sends an event $\omega \in \Omega$ to some Borel set $B \in B(\mathbb{R})$. So $X_n(w) = P(X_n^{-1}(B)) = P_{X_n}(B)$ where $P_{X_n}$ is the distribution of the random variable $X_n$.

So then does that mean that $X_n \rightarrow X$ if the distribution of $X_n$ tends to $X$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, $X_n(\omega) \in B \in B(\mathbb{R})$ does not imply $X_n(\omega) \ne P(X_n^{-1}(B))$.  We could take $B = \mathbb{R}$ for an easy counterexample, as $P(X_n^{-1}(\mathbb{R})) = 1$ but $X_n(\omega)$ can be arbitrary.

Additionally, "the distribution of $X_n$ tends to $X$" is convergence in distribution, which is a separate concept to pointwise convergence.  You can have convergence in distribution without having pointwise convergence.

Comment: Ok I see. The reason I asked this question is that I am trying to find the expectation of a poisson rv as an exercise for a course. This course has only taught me how to find the expectation of simple rvs, and how to approximate a discrete rv by a sequence of simple rvs. I also know that the binomial distribution converges to the poisson one, so i was hoping to approximate the poisson rv by a sequence of binomial rvs. But this convergence is in terms of distribution. So is this the completely wrong approach? @user6247850

Comment: See how important context is for a question. To find the expectation of a Poisson variable $N$ you simply calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\mathbb P(N=n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$. Hint: this should give $\lambda$.

Comment: @Jamal I think you can just compute the expectation directly using $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n P(X=n)$.  If you wanted to be very formal with it, you can use that if $X$ is a Poisson random variable, then $X1_{X \le N}$ is a simple random variable that you can compute the expectation of as a partial sum, and then take the limit of the partial sums.  Convergence in distribution _can_ imply convergence of means in some cases, but I think the direct approach will be easier.

Comment: @KurtG. user6247850 thanks for the replies. I know how to calculate expectation of a discrete rv directly, but I am trying to avoid this as it has not been taught in my course yet. So far I can only calculate expectations of simple rvs (one that takes finitely many values) or of discrete rvs by the convergence theorem in the question. What I don't get is how to show that an rv converges in the pointwise functional sense. How can I find a sequence of simple rvs that converge to my poisson rv?

Comment: @Jamal I just gave you a sequence of simple rvs $X_N$ that converge pointwise to the poisson $X$: $X 1_{X \le N}$ takes on only the values $\{0,1,...,N\}$ and converges pointwise to $X$ (because $X_N(\omega)=X(\omega)$ for all $N$ sufficiently large ("sufficiently large" depends on $\omega$, but that's fine)).